# LINQ get search options with counts by user selection

Tags: .net, sql-server, linq, asp.net-core

I have an web application. I use .NET Core 5 and SPA. I have a form with search options. Width columns like widths, rim diameters, heights etc. I am trying to get available options by user selection in single query throught api.

I have no idea how to do this. I can do this with many queries, but its not good performance. My current code is terrible and not working.

Please, help me. Thank you

[image]

```cs
[HttpGet("filter")]
public IActionResult Filter([FromQuery] ProductParameters parameters)
{
    // parameters.Brands = new List<Brand>();
    parameters.TakeCount = null;
    IQueryable<Product> products = _productRepository.FindByCondition(s => s.ProductType == parameters.ProductType); // _productRepository.GetByParameters(parameters);

    ProductTiresSearchFilterModel model = new ProductTiresSearchFilterModel()
    {
        ResultsCount = products.Count()
    };

    parameters.TakeCount = null;
    

    var brands = products.Where(s => s.Brand != null && (s.TireWidth == parameters.TireWidth || parameters.TireWidth == null));

    var objectCounts = products
        .Where(s => s.TireWidth != null)
            .GroupBy(s => new { s.ProductCondition, s.Brand, s.TireWidth })
            .Select(group => new
            {
                brands = new ProductSearchOption(Convert.ToInt32(group.Key.Brand), group.Key.Brand.Value.GetDescription(),
                group.Where(s => s.Brand != null && (s.TireWidth == parameters.TireWidth || parameters.TireWidth == null)).Count()),
                conditions = new ProductSearchOption(Convert.ToInt32(group.Key.ProductCondition), TireHelper.GetConditionLabel(group.Key.ProductCondition), group.Count()),
                tireWidths = new ProductSearchOption(Convert.ToInt32(group.Key.TireWidth), group.Key.TireWidth.Value.ToString(), group.Count(s => s.TireWidth != null)),
            };

    model.Brands = objectCounts
            .Select(s => s.brands)
        .GroupBy(s => s.Value)
        .Select(s => new ProductSearchOption(s.Key, ((Brand)s.Key).GetDescription(), s.Count()))
        .ToList();

    model.Conditions = objectCounts
        .Select(s => s.conditions)
        .GroupBy(s => s.Value)
        .Select(s => new ProductSearchOption(s.Key, TireHelper.GetConditionLabel((ProductCondition)s.Key), s.Count()))
        .ToList();

    model.Widths = objectCounts
        .Select(s => s.tireWidths)
        .GroupBy(s => s.Value)
        .Select(s => new ProductSearchOption(s.Key, s.Key.ToString(), s.Count()))
        .ToList();

    return Ok(model);

public class ProductSearchOption
{
    public ProductSearchOption(int value, string label, int resultsCount)
    {
        this.Value = value;
        this.Label = label;
        this.ResultsCount = resultsCount;
    }

    public int Value { get; set; }

    public string Label { get; set; }

    public int ResultsCount { get; set; }
}

public class ProductTiresSearchFilterModel
{
    public List<ProductSearchOption> Conditions = new List<ProductSearchOption> { };

    public List<ProductSearchOption> Seasons = new List<ProductSearchOption> { };

    public List<ProductSearchOption> VehicleTypes = new List<ProductSearchOption> { };

    public List<ProductSearchOption> Widths = new List<ProductSearchOption> { };

    public List<ProductSearchOption> Heights = new List<ProductSearchOption> { };

    public List<ProductSearchOption> RimDiameters = new List<ProductSearchOption> { };


    public List<ProductSearchOption> Brands = new List<ProductSearchOption> { };


    public List<ProductSearchOption> LoadIndexes = new List<ProductSearchOption> { };

    public List<ProductSearchOption> SpeedRatings = new List<ProductSearchOption> { };


    public int ResultsCount { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastEditDateUtc { get; set; }

    public DateTime ExpirationDateUtc { get; set; }

    public bool External { get; set; }

    public string ExternalLink { get; set; }

    public bool Deleted { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Slug { get; set; }

    public virtual Place Place { get; set; }

    public Guid? PlaceId { get; set; }

    [Column("UserId")]
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public string SourceUrl { get; set; }

    public bool? VatDeduction { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public ProductCondition ProductCondition { get; set; }

    public Brand? Brand { get; set; }

    public Country? Origin { get; set; }

    public string Vin { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(60)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ProductType ProductType { get; set; }

    public TransmissionType? TransmissionType { get; set; }

    public FuelType? FuelType { get; set; }

    public VehicleBody? VehicleBody { get; set; }

    public int PriceCzk { get; set; }

    public int? PriceEur { get; set; }

    public bool PriceByAgreement { get; set; }

    public int? Mileage { get; set; }

    public int? Power { get; set; }

    public int? NumberOfSeats { get; set; }

    public int? DoorCount { get; set; }

    public int? NumberOfVehicleOwners { get; set; }
    
    public int? CubicCapacity { get; set; }

    public int? MaximumSpeed { get; set; }

    #region Equipment 

    public bool? AirConditioner { get; set; }
    public bool? IndependentHeating { get; set; }
    public bool? StartStop { get; set; }
    public bool? Radio { get; set; }
    public bool? Bluetooth { get; set; }
    public bool? CruiseControl { get; set; }
    public bool? ElectricMirrors { get; set; }
    public bool? ParkingSensor { get; set; }
    public bool? Esp { get; set; }
    public bool? RainSensor { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Tires 

    public int? TireWidth { get; set; }

    public int? TireHeight { get; set; }

    public int? TireRimDiameter { get; set; }

    public int? TireLoadIndex { get; set; }

    public TireConstructionType? TireConstructionType { get; set; }

    public TireSeason? TireSeason { get; set; }

    public TireVehicleType? TireVehicleType { get; set; }

    public TireSpeedRating? TireSpeedRating { get; set; }

    public int? TireMaximumSpeed { get; set; }

//  public 
    #endregion

    public virtual ICollection<ProductUser> ProductUsers { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProductImage> ProductImages { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Add to question main thing - class `ProductTiresSearchFilterModel` and class `Product`

Comment: I have added. Thanks :-)

Comment: Fetch everything to memory by adding `ToList()` on `objectCounts` initialization?

Comment: @AdamGajdečka, as mentioned by Guru Strin, put .ToList() when generating objectCounts. And rest of grouping will be done on the client side.

Comment: Should I get to list a thousends of items? I don't want to fetch all items from client. I am using paging. I need return grouped counts from server.